# how do i fix ssl exception error and load https in android webview

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview, ssl-certificate

I am trying to load https side in webview but it will give me ssl certificate error. my site have already ssl certificate so i don't understand why it is not allowing to load secure url.  i follow some some codes the provide below code but my client required he did not want to appear dialog box before site is load. so how do i load my site with ssl certificate. Any idea?   i don't want to use beloew solution.

```
       @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
//            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
//            builder.setMessage(R.string.notification_error_ssl_cert_invalid);
//            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                    handler.proceed();
//                }
//            });
//            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
//                    handler.cancel();
//                    finish();
//                }
//            });
//            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
//            dialog.show();





            String msg="";
            if(error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_DATE_INVALID
                    || error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_EXPIRED
                    || error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH
                    || error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_INVALID
                    || error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID
                    || error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED) {
                if(error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_DATE_INVALID){
                    msg="The date of the certificate is invalid";
                }else if(error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_INVALID){
                    msg="A generic error occurred";
                }
                else if(error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_EXPIRED){
                    msg="The certificate has expired";
                }else if(error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH){
                    msg="Hostname mismatch";
                }
                else if(error.getPrimaryError()== SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID){
                    msg="The certificate is not yet valid";
                }
                else if(error.getPrimaryError()==SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED){
                    msg="The certificate authority is not trusted";
                }
            }
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setMessage(msg);
            builder.setPositiveButton("continue", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.proceed();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    handler.cancel();
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();




        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need your certificate for HTTPS connections you can add the .bks file as a raw resource to your application and extend DefaultHttpConnection so your certificates are used for HTTPS connections.

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    private Resources resources;

    public MyHttpClient(Resources resources) {
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @Override
    protected ClientConnectionManager createClientConnectionManager() {
        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
            .getSocketFactory(), 80));
        if (resources != null) {
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", newSslSocketFactory(), 443));
        } else {
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", SSLSocketFactory
                .getSocketFactory(), 443));
        }
        return new SingleClientConnManager(getParams(), registry);
    }

    private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
        try {
            KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
            InputStream in = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.mystore);
            try {
                trusted.load(in, "pwd".toCharArray());
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }
            return new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

This may solve your HTTPS ssl certificate error.

### Alternative Solution

Use following code

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new SSLTolerentWebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl(myhttps url);
```

and SSLTolerentWebViewClient class

```
private class SSLTolerentWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab1Activity.this);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
        switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
            case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
                message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
                message = "The certificate has expired.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
                message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
                break;
            case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
                message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
                break;
        }

        message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
        alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);
        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Ignore SSL certificate errors
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                handler.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: how i can use this with my webview ?

Comment: problem is i have handle all this things but whenever i load application it will show dialog before load website... if i will remove dialog play store suspend my app. at once app is suspended. my client irritate with itz dialog box ....here is my apk check bug https://i.diawi.com/AoKDiP

Comment: i can't find your apk

Answer (score 0):

Because, When you are making the request from your mobile(client) to your server, the server will send the some encrypted data to your mobile(client).so that data need to be decrypted via that certificate file. so you need to install proper .cer  (or) .crt file in your mobile . After that, your problem may get resolved.

**UPDATE**

I have added the code. Here you just pass your SSL certificate as inputstream format in setCustomCertificateAuthority() method.

```
public class SslCertificateAuthority {

private static class UnifiedTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    private X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager;
    private X509TrustManager localTrustManager;
    public UnifiedTrustManager(KeyStore localKeyStore) throws KeyStoreException {
        try {
            this.defaultTrustManager = createTrustManager(null);
            this.localTrustManager = createTrustManager(localKeyStore);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private X509TrustManager createTrustManager(KeyStore store) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init((KeyStore) store);
        TrustManager[] trustManagers = tmf.getTrustManagers();
        return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
    }
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            defaultTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        } catch (CertificateException ce) {
            localTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            defaultTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
        } catch (CertificateException ce) {
            localTrustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        X509Certificate[] first = defaultTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        X509Certificate[] second = localTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        X509Certificate[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }
}

public static void setCustomCertificateAuthority(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

    try {
        // Load CAs from an InputStream
        // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore and system CA
        UnifiedTrustManager trustManager = new UnifiedTrustManager(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{trustManager}, null);

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: how do i get install that .crt or .cer file in android application?

Comment: ask your network admin who installed your web server.this is like encrypt decryption technique only.

Comment: let me check i ll back to you